# Sending json array as querystring in senchatouch2

Tags: arrays, json, sencha-touch-2, query-string

Should we send **json array** or **normal array** as querystring in senchatouch2

Comment: What do you mean "as query string?"

Comment: To access webservice,we will send querystring parameters knw

Comment: To store details in Database,we have to use WEBSERVICE to access that database..Using POST method i send the values as QueryString which is appended to webserviceURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we use POST method to send parameters in Sencha Touch2 use **jsonData** in Ajax Request like,

> Ext.Ajax.request({
>       url:'',
>       method:'POST',
>       disableCaching:false,
>       headers: {
>               'Accept':'application/json',
>               'Content-Type':'application/json'
>       },
>       **jsonData**: {
>                 FirstName:fname  //{"FirstName":["Sam","paul"]}
>       },
>       success: function(response)
>       {
>        console.log(response.responseText);
>       },
>       failure: function(response)
>       {
>        console.log(response.responseText);
>       },
>   });

Answer (score 0):

in any case you can only send String in URL so if you have JSON then use [Ext.JSON.encode](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.JSON-method-encode) to make it string and if you have JS Array use `toString` or `join` method to flatten the array before appending it to URL.

Since you said querystring so I suppose you and not doing POST request.

[EDIT]
Looking at your comment it seems you want to send some data to service for creation but in that case you should not send data as querystring, you should send it in message body. Following is example to send JSON data to your service:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.loginEntry  = new Object();
obj.loginEntry.userid = username;
obj.loginEntry.password = password;
var data = Ext.JSON.encode(obj);
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url : 'http://myserver:port/service/entity',
        method : "POST",
        headers: {
            /* Important because default is 
             * Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 
             * which is not supported by service
             */
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        params : data,
        success : function(response) {
        },
        failure : function(response) {
        }
    }
);
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: we should not use POST method huh?

Comment: if i send querystring as Array it is passing as ["Annie","Rose"], But if converted to String it is passing as Annie,Rose   Which is correct?

Comment: check out my answers, I have added sample code to show POST request

Comment: Another doubt..I wanna append 5 arrays to URL, like Passenger's FirstName as one array,then Title,then DOB,LastName and PassengerCode..Should i send each array separately or i must send in a single array as u specified

Comment: I created array like var fname_array = [] and added values using push() method..Is tat right way?

Comment: it all depends on what your service interface expects. Generally they expect JSON or XML so its better to create JSON object as I shown and post it to your service

Comment: k ill post the webservice code also..check it once and update me whether problem s in webservice or senchatouch code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012922/sending-array-as-parameters-using-post-method-in-senchatouch2.. Plz refer this link..I posted webservice code and senchatouch code.. Kindly update me