# Sending array as parameters using POST method in senchatouch2

Tags: arrays, wcf, post, parameters

Using this service i want to store array value into database using POST method in senchatouch2..Service is written in (WCF)

**Service declaration :**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
           UriTemplate = "/Check1")]
int Psngr(string[] FirstName);
```

**Service definition :**

```
public static int Psngr(string[] FirstName)
{  
    List<Psgr> psgr = new List<Psgr>();
    var getVal = from s in FirstName select s;
    int count = getVal.Count();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ToString());
    con.Open();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_InsertCheck1", con))
    {
        int result;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName[i]);

            using (var Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            using (var Ds = new DataSet())
            {
                Da.Fill(Ds);
                result = Convert.ToInt16(Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Result"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I accesssed this service through my ajax request as follows:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'http://ws.easy4booking.com/E4b.svc/Check1',                                                   
    method:'POST',                                            
    disableCaching: false,                                          
    headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    params: {
        FirstName:fname_toString,  //FirstName:["Sam","Paul"],
},
    success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

When I accessed this service lik mentioned above i got following error

**Request Error:**

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'Psngr'. Encountered unexpected character 'F'.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
> isOperationContextSet)

Comment: I would say that you monitor on how the Raw request looks like. Use tools like Fiddler or WireShark to see the raw request. Also you can enable tracing on the WCF service and see what is causing the issue.

Comment: I dont understand where s d exact problem..Problem s in sencha code or service? kindly reply me

Comment: Enable wcf trace, use svcTraceViewer.exe to view them IMO - this will help to find WHERE the error comes from.

Comment: Also, Are you sure you sending array and not string?

Comment: Yes m sure m sending ARRAY oly ..my array pass lik FirstName:["Annie","Dev","Anish","Angel"]

Comment: From the error i guess your request is not formed properly. Note that you have set the body style to be wrapped. So i would suggest you start Fiddler or WireShark and then make the call to the WCF REST service and inspect the Raw request and if you can post it should be easy to help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When v use POST method to pass parameters in SenchaTouch2 use **jsonData** in Ajax Request like,

> Ext.Ajax.request({
>       url:'',
>       method:'POST',
>       disableCaching:false,
>       headers: {
>               'Accept':'application/json',
>               'Content-Type':'application/json'
>       },
>       **jsonData**: {
>                 FirstName:fname  //{"FirstName":["Sam","paul"]}
>       },
>       success: function(response)
>       {
>        console.log(response.responseText);
>       },
>       failure: function(response)
>       {
>        console.log(response.responseText);
>       },
>   });

Answer (score 0):

When your client does a request to the WCF Rest service the raw request should look something like below:

```
POST http://localhost/SampleService/RestService/Check1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 33

{"FirstName":["Sam","paul"]}
```

Seems like your sencha code is passing the string[] which WCF is not able to deserialize. You might consider to pass it as jsonData rather than param.

Also look at this [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?255470-Not-able-to-PUT-json-array-in-Ext.ajax.request) which might help.(The service they are trying to consume is in Spring MVC but i guess it should be the same for WCF service as well)

Comment: i changed params to jsonData,now its working fine..Thanks a lot 4 ur kind reply

Comment: For GET method we should use params AND for POST method we should use jsonData huh?

Comment: @Annie: Would be nice if you can mark it as answer so that it might be helpful for someone with the same problem